# Dynamic interface key with TypeScript

Tags: typescript

I'd like to define the object keys of my interface dynamically, where the key names come from variables.

Is there any way to do that?

```
const key1 = 'hello';
const key2 = 'world';

interface MyInterface {
  [key1]: {};
  [key2]: string;
}

const myObject: MyInterface = {
  [key1]: {
    something: 'something',
  },
  [key2]: 'some other things'
}
```

I currently get the following error with the above:

> A computed property name in an interface must directly refer to a built-in symbol

Thanks.

Comment: [typescript ≠ javascript](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/320279/should-pure-coffeescript-questions-tag-javascript/320280#320280)

Comment: Variable values aren't known/evaluated until runtime. Interfaces are purely static information for the compiler/static type checker. This cannot really work without some sort of special "static Typescript variables", which don't exist. Why do you want this in the first place?

Answer (score 0):

No, this cannot currently be done.  There is an [issue on GitHub](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/5579) which asks for this; you might want to head over there and give it a .

For now, this is the closest you can do:

```
const key1 = 'hello';
const key2 = 'world';

type _MyInterface = Record<typeof key1, {}> & Record<typeof key2, string>;
interface MyInterface extends _MyInterface { }

var _myObject = {} as MyInterface;
_myObject[key1] = { something: 'something' };
_myObject[key2] = 'some other things';
const myObject = _myObject;
```

This more or less has the same meaning as your code, albeit uglier and harder to follow.

Hope that helps; good luck!